# Why is "setMaxLifecycle" an alternative to "getUserVisibleHint"?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development.
I'm importing "androidx.fragment.app.Fragment".

'getUserVisibleHint()' is deprecated.
So, I want to use setMaxLifecycle(). But, I can't understand.

Why is "setMaxLifecycle" an alternative to "getUserVisibleHint"?
Why is "set" an alternative to "get"?

```
if (getUserVisibleHint())
{

}
```

Will this happen?
What do you set in the argument?
I don't understand at all even if I read the reference.

```
if (setMaxLifecycle())
{

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There's no non-deprecated API that calls `setUserVisibleHint()` in the first place, so this if check doesn't make any sense at all.